# How to download dropbox pictures locally to a folder with javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, dropbox-api

In my vue application I am getting right now the meta information from one image. What I want to do is to save this file to a local folder inside my project. But right now I am stuck at that. Could someone give me a pointer on how to do it? Here is my code for to get the meta information.

```js
getImages() {
  const Dropbox = require("dropbox").Dropbox;
  let pictures2 = [];
  const dbx = new Dropbox({
    accessToken:
      "<REDACTED>",
  });
  dbx
    .filesDownload({
      path: "/test/road-6576857_1920.jpg",
    })
    .then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}}
```

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/How-to-save-pictures-inside-an-array-and-then-display/m-p/546900#M26068 ]

Comment: Does "to a local folder" mean on your `Node` server (not to the client device)? If so, the docs seem to indicate that the [.filesDownload](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload__anchor) SDK method you're using does indeed "Download a file from a user's Dropbox", not just copy some metadata ...
Alternatively, Dropbox's [Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser#js) interface may be useful to you.

Comment: Yes I want to download to the project folder and then convert it later on to pdf with a different  method. The chooser would not really achieve what I want right now. My client wants this to download and automatically convert to pdf without him having to select pictures and then convert each of them manually